# Error in android studio while creating a new project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, socketexception

I got this error message while I tried to create a new project in Android studio :

```
Failed to import Gradle project: Error unmarshaling return header; 
nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Go to Gradle
Download last version
Open grandle location within Android Studio (in my case is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle"
Important: backup your existing Android Studio gradle lib folder (in case things go wrong, as some of the commenters have pointed out)
Open download file from 2.
Override lib folder within Android Studio with lib folder within downloaded file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was the same error, I resolved it with this solution :

```
Open the SDK manager
Make sure that the "Extras/Android Support Repository" (not just Android Support Library) is installed or updated.
```

> Source: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio020released

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Fix described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59142#c8) workes for me.  -Dexternal.system.in.process=true setting is needed in VM options of Android Studio.